# How to work with dynamic domain?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

what I need is once I select patient when I search to select nameLab I wanna to show the only Lab that is related to the selected patient (patient_id should = patient).

my classes:

```py
class labinvoice (models.Model):
    _name = "lab.invoice"

    order_line = fields.One2many('lab.order.line', 'order_id', string='Order Lines', copy=True)
    nameLab = fields.Many2one('medical.lab.patient',related='order_line.namelab')
    patient = fields.Many2one('medical.patient',related='order_line.patient_id')
    patient_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='medical.patient',required=True, )

class LabOrderLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'lab.order.line'

    nameLab = fields.Many2one(
        string='Lab',
        comodel_name='medical.lab.patient',
        required=True,
        ondelete='cascade',
    )

    patient= fields.Many2one(
        'medical.patient',
        string='patient',
         related='nameLab.patient_id',
         readonly=True,
        required=True,
    )
```

my view:

```html
<record id="view_invoice_lab_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">lab.invoice.form</field>
            <field name="model">lab.invoice</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Labs Invoices" class="o_sale_order">
                <sheet>
                    <div class="oe_title">
                        <h1>
                            <field name="name" readonly="1"/>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="patient_id" />
                        </group>
                      
                    </group>
                    <notebook>
                        <page string="Order Lines">
                            <field name="order_line" mode="tree,kanban">
                                <tree string="labs Order Lines" editable="bottom" >
                                  <field name="nameLab" />
                                   <field name="patient" /> 
                                </tree>                                
                           </field>
                       </page> 
                </notebook>
            </sheet>       
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

What I'm  m trying to do is something like saleOrder but instead of choosing customers here I choose patients and instead of choosing products I should choose the nameLab related to the patient choosed

```py
    @api.onchange('patient_id')
    def onchange_patient(self):
        if self.patient_id:
        #to clean the line everytime i change the patient
            self.order_line = False
            return {'domain':{'nameLab':[('patient','=',self.patient_id.id)]}}
```

think the problem is due to the one2many relation

Answer (score 2):

We can work this onchange of parent okk!!

we are dealing this because the function can return a domain on the onchange itself...

like -->

@api.onchange('patient')

def onchange_patient(self):

```
if self.patient:
    return {'domain':{'namelab':[('id','in',self.patient.namelab.ids)]}}
```

thinking that it helps

Vishnu

Comment: thanks for ur answer .  but it gives me this error :                                                                                       return {'domain':{'namelab':[('id','in',self.patient_id.namelab.ids)]}}
AttributeError: 'medical.patient' object has no attribute 'namelab'

Comment: You don't need to use `onchange`. In this case it can be done with domain and it will be a cleaner solution.

Comment: I tried to work with onchange with domain in vain. no result... think the problem is due to the order_line (one2many)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `domain`, which can be set on your field in Python or XML, but typically XML is the most common way to use it.

The way your form is designed now, you would make this update.

`<field name="nameLab" domain="[('partner_id', '=', partner)]"/>`

See the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/views.html) for more details.

Comment: it returns no nameLab

Comment: Can you update your question with the full view and the error?